# Possibility of including Java code into XSLT1.0 file from web?

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I'm wondering, is there any possibility to include java code into my XSLT1.0 file from other source than classpath (I dont have an acces into classpath files), like github for example or some web solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    xmlns:test="http://github.com/user/test.java">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <out>
    <xsl:value-of select="test:function()"/>
  </out>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that this is Xalan specific , not vanilla XSLT.

Comment: The class path does not contain any source files, it contains the compiled `.class` files or `.jar` files containing the compiled files. I don't think there is a way to link to Java source code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen even if it is xalan specific, is it possible with xalan? it seems like xalan jar or something is included in classpath

Comment: You can call any method. Can you write the Java code that gives what you want in a string ?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen even a simple "hello world" would be some advantage to me for the future development

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve?